# Stanford NLP core not producing 'Before' and 'After' nodes in tokenization

Tags: stanford-nlp

Running the current version Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.1 (updated 2018/04/05) as http server.

Using the default .properties that comes with each different language download:

The French output is missing the `'before'` and `'after'` nodes.

```
 "tokens": [
        {
          "index": 1,
          "word": "Je",
          "originalText": "Je",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 2,
          "pos": "PRON"
        },
```

Whereas all the other Latin languages available e.g. German - include the nodes.

```
 {
      "index": 2,
      "word": "durchgecheckt",
      "originalText": "durchgecheckt",
      "characterOffsetBegin": 10,
      "characterOffsetEnd": 23,
      "pos": "VVPP",
      "before": " ",
      "after": " "
    },
```

How to do set it, to include them in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same issue with version 3.9.2 ?

I think in 3.9.2 you want these options:

```
tokenize.options = ellipses=ptb3,normalizeParentheses=true,ptb3Dashes=false,splitContractions=true,splitCompounds=true,invertible=true"
```

We're trying to release version 4.0.0 fairly soon with new tokenization for French that is designed to match modern Universal Dependencies data sets.